# why load() is different from loadByIncrementId() for sales/order model

Tags: model, sales-order

I am getting order details through `sales/order` by using `load(order_id)`. But load does not give the data, but `loadIncrementById()` returns the order data.

What is the difference between these `load()` and `loadIncrementById()`?and which situation these are used?

Is all model can be extracted by using these methods?

Comment: are you using the same parameter for `load` and `loadByIncrementId`?

Comment: Yes @Marius I used order_id.

Comment: Then, what Luke answered below explains it nicely.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

sales_flat_orders has its primary key "entity_id". This is what you try to load when you use function load()

```
$order->load(12345)
select entity_id, increment_id from sales_flat_order where entity_id=12345;
```

vs

```
$order->loadByIncrementId(12345)
select entity_id, increment_id from sales_flat_order where increment_id=12345;
```

Most models are loaded by their primary key, and the simple load() function.

However there are a few nice little functions like this scattered about the place, another example would be Mage::getModel('customer/customer')->loadByEmail()

Comment: But when i log the result of both methods they are different why?.

Comment: Where are you retrieving the order_id that you want to load? It will be because entity_id in the database is not equal to increment_id in the database.


Whatever is giving you the order_id that you are using, is actually returning you the orders increment_id.


So when you try and do a load, you're trying to load an order by entity_id when using the increment_id. This order does not exist, which gives you different values.